# Postgresql 9.0 is running in bg by default

Tags: postgresql, freebsd

I found that postgresql v9.0.7 is running in bg mode by default when it is started ( Command below ). Earlier when we were using postgresql v7.4.2 it used to run in foreground mode.

I am using freebsd 8.2 64 bit environment. Postgresql v9.0.7 is built with WITHOUT_XML, WITHOUT_GETTEXT and WITHOUT_GNUGEOPT options set.

c670e04:rkananth 16] /usr/local/bin/postgres --version
    postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.0.7

```
c670e04:rkananth 7] setenv PGDATA /data/db/postgres/
c670e04:rkananth 11] /data/bin/runas pgsql /usr/local/bin/postgres
c670e04:rkananth 12] ps -A | grep post
65165  ??  Ss     0:00.01 /usr/local/bin/postgres
65167  ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: writer process    (postgres)
65168  ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: wal writer process    (postgres)
65169  ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    (postgres)
65170  ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process    (postgres)
65224   0  S+     0:00.00 grep post

c670e04:rkananth 14] ps -p 65165 -o ppid
 PPID
    1
c670e04:rkananth 15] ps 1
  PID  TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    1  ??  SLs    0:00.17 /sbin/init --
c670e04:rkananth 16]
```

Are there any way where I can force it to come foreground?

Also looking at the above log, it shows that the server process's parent is set to 1 ( init) is it expected behavior when server runs in bg mode ?

However documentation for 9.0.7 says by default it should come in foreground. Why is this not happening in my case, may be a bug?

**Update 1:** 
/data/bin/runas is not introducing any behavior change, tested without it. Same behavior is is also seen in v8.3 and on Freebsd 7.2 32-bit environment.

Server process becoming child of PID 1 ( init ) looks like a standard behavior of any application runs as a daemon.

My question now is - Is there a way where I can instruct Postgres not to run as Daemon ?

**Update 2:**
Got the solution it is the config  "silent_mode = off" (By default it is on) will make it to run in foreground and process runs as child process of the shell. With this the question is answered. 
( Source  - http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/BUG-4381-Postgresql-daemon-won-t-stay-in-the-foreground-td2127518.html )

Comment: I'm curious (I have no real experience with *nix): what difference does it make?

Comment: It doesn't do that on linux, self-compiled. Are you 100% sure that `/usr/local/bin/postgresql` is the actual postgres binary and not a wrapper? And is it self-compiled or pre-compiled?

Comment: Daniel: I am 100% sure that /usr/local/bin/postgresql is the right binary. 
I tested on self compiled installation as well as installation through ports. Same behavior is seen.

Comment: Personally I think the process is just forking itself but not really daemonizing. As @dschulz already suggested, try it in a local shell without runas first and see if that works.

Comment: WoLpH: 
I have tested without runas. Please see my above comment addressing Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `postgres` should stay in the foreground, as stated in the manpage:

> By default postgres starts in the foreground and prints log
>   messages to the standard error stream. In practical applications
>   postgres should be started as a background process, perhaps at
>   boot time.

Most likely the `runas` command is what daemonizes the `postgres` process. Try running `postgres` from a shell started as `pgsql` user:

```
root# su - pgsql
pgsql$ setenv PGDATA /data/db/postgres/
pgsql$ /usr/local/bin/postgres
```

You can also try with `su(1)` and `sudo(8)` if you don't like the idea of a shell as `pgsql` user.

Now I'm wondering why you need `postgres` to run in the foreground. Do you really have a good reason?

Comment: runas does not daemonizes for sure. It is the our way of doing exactly the stuff that you have mentioned. I want it to be foreground because, we have a watchdog which watches on the PID of the shell where this command is executed, when it goes bg, shell gets terminated and watchdog thinks server died and tries to restart  and fails ( as server already running )